# What is self.pool.get() in python and odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I assume it is used to refer fields in other modules in openerp, but I am not sure.

Here they are somehow getting price from one products module to sales module.

```
price = self.pool.get('product.pricelist').price_get(cr, uid, [pricelist], product, qty or 1.0, partner_id, ctx)[pricelist]
    if price is False:
        warn_msg = _("Cannot find a pricelist line matching this product and quantity.\n"
                "You have to change either the product, the quantity or the pricelist.")

        warning_msgs += _("No valid pricelist line found ! :") + warn_msg +"\n\n"
    else:
        result.update({'price_unit': price})
        if context.get('uom_qty_change', False):
            return {'value': {'price_unit': price}, 'domain': {}, 'warning': False}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***self.pool.get()***

The `pool` is here just a dictionary-like object that is used to store instances of the `OpenERP models`, like `res.users` or `ir.model.data`.

**Multi-database nature of OpenERP / Odoo:** a single OpenERP server process can manage multiple databases, and for each database, the set of installed modules, and thus the set of models, can vary.

So, we have different `pools`, one per database, and the normal way to reference the model instance we are already in, **`self`**

Thanks to [The Hypered Blog](http://hypered.io/blog/2013-12-30-self-pool-get/) for the great explanation on the **`self.pool.get()`**. 
For more info check that link.

Answer (score 5):

**Pool**

> pool is a registry (dictionary object {}).
>
> The registry is essentially a mapping between model names and model
>   instances. There is one registry instance per database.

**server/openerp/osv/orm.py**

```
class BaseModel(object):

    def __init__(self, pool, cr):
```

> ```
>     """ Initialize a model and make it part of the given registry.
>
>         - copy the stored fields' functions in the osv_pool,
>         - update the _columns with the fields found in ir_model_fields,
>         - ensure there is a many2one for each _inherits'd parent,
>         - update the children's _columns,
>         - give a chance to each field to initialize itself.
>
>         """
> ```

```
        pool.add(self._name, self)
        self.pool = pool
```

> Refer **/openerp/sql_db.py** to see how **Odoo-Postgresql connection
>   pool** establish.

```
_Pool = None

def db_connect(to, allow_uri=False):
    global _Pool
    if _Pool is None:
        _Pool = ConnectionPool(int(tools.config['db_maxconn']))

    db, uri = dsn(to)
    if not allow_uri and db != to:
        raise ValueError('URI connections not allowed')
    return Connection(_Pool, db, uri)

def close_db(db_name):
    """ You might want to call openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.delete(db_name) along this function."""
    global _Pool
    if _Pool:
        _Pool.close_all(dsn(db_name)[1])

def close_all():
    global _Pool
    if _Pool:
        _Pool.close_all()
```

**Connection class**

```
class Connection(object):
    """ A lightweight instance of a connection to postgres
    """
    def __init__(self, pool, dbname, dsn):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.__pool = pool
```

if you look at the  **/server/openerp/pooler.py** file there you can find the method **get_db_and_pool** which is used to Create and return a database connection and a newly initialized registry, there are many other methods related to pool look at these.

```
def get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo=False, status=None, update_module=False):
    """Create and return a database connection and a newly initialized registry."""
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
    return registry.db, registry


def restart_pool(db_name, force_demo=False, status=None, update_module=False):
    """Delete an existing registry and return a database connection and a newly initialized registry."""
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
    return registry.db, registry

def get_db(db_name):
    """Return a database connection. The corresponding registry is initialized."""
    return get_db_and_pool(db_name)[0]


def get_pool(db_name, force_demo=False, status=None, update_module=False):
    """Return a model registry."""
    return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
```

And finally you call get method of dictionary to get the value of the specified key, even you can use can use **self.pool['model_name']**, any method of dictionary can be used with pool.

Answer (score 3):

`self.pool.get()` is used to get the Singleton instance of the orm model from the registry pool.

If you want to call orm methods for any other model you can use `self.pool.get('model').orm_method`

And in new API, if you want to call ORM method directly from an object you can use `self.env['obj'].method` instead of `self.method`

Hope this helps.